# Coping with Date Nightmares

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I'm currently coping with a cesspool of date formats in a string field that I'm trying to untangle. I'm working exclusively in SQL Server.

I have a field that has dates that are all over the place.

Does anyone know of a good function or Github project that can help?

For example I have stuff like:

- cool file 1 - 2018-05-12
- File2 04-18-20
- 26.02.20 - another crazy format
- shootmenow-2019.02-23.INeedAnAsprin
- Impossible_But_Ill_Take_Whatever_10-11-12

I'd like to get a normalized data out of this but some rudimentary checking of illegal values.

I can feed it a `##.##.##` parameter if I have to but if there's something magical out there that can take a `varchar` parameter and spit out a date, I'd rather take advantage of it.

Anything you can point me to would be great.

Comment: Load the data into tables in the database and convert to a `date` column.  SQL Server is rarely used to process files directly.

Comment: Can build a quick stored function, however for formats without complete year part it will always be challenging untill you set a rule for the function to decide when to return 19XX and 20XX. For ex: When XX is between 00-20 return 20XX and 21-99 return 19XX.

Comment: Generally speaking, it can not be done. In many cases, those numbers do not determine exact date if you do not know for sure the format. I would try to rethink the approach. Can you get the date elsewhere? Or the format?

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression, or rather *several* regular expressions can get the job done. The problem is how to differentiate month from day eg: `Impossible_But_Ill_Take_Whatever_10-11-12`. 
This is very ambiguous. A regex cannot magically tell month from day or even year in a case like this.

- `2018-05-12` is easy to handle - if it's YYYY-MM-DD it can be converted to date downright
- As for `26.02.20` assuming the year is 2020 it can be converted to date using 'German' format: `SELECT CONVERT (datetime, '26.02.20', 4)` - see [CAST and CONVERT - Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms187928(v%3dsql.110))
- As for `04-18-20`: `SELECT CONVERT (datetime, '04-18-20', 10)` (USA format)

I'm afraid you will need to evaluate the different scenarios and use different approaches. What I would do is:

- create a copy of the table
- select records that have a similar date format with a LIKE or a regex, then perform bulk replacement after a visual check
- flag the records as done

If you are lucky you will be left a small number of rows to be fixed manually.
But I fear some records are irrecoverable because they are ambiguous.